# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fromarray'

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am having an image array with shape `(256, 256)`

```
array([[ 1.83929426,  2.27074315,  2.5218986 , ...,  5.58716559,
         7.68013398,  8.48954239],
       [ 7.7554863 ,  1.80131326,  4.08562626, ..., 11.43703752,
        10.6897957 ,  2.21642752],
       [ 3.5976206 , 17.32215998,  3.94093576, ...,  2.92133073,
         5.27458118,  6.51157218],
       ...,
       [12.61920987,  5.42883218,  4.91278887, ..., 11.86499776,
         1.95860585,  1.96206125],
       [ 4.18047027,  2.85057039, 11.86617946, ...,  3.56434097,
         8.87239311,  2.14273459],
       [ 5.36091217,  9.16876533,  2.52525961, ...,  8.17177924,
         3.85081341,  6.46705723]])
```

when i try to load using `Image.fromarray()` i am getting error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fromarray'`

code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import loadmat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matcontent = loadmat('/content/PIfile_new.mat', appendmat=True)
matcontent.keys()

highest = np.max(matcontent['I32'])
lowest = np.min(matcontent['I32'])
print(highest, lowest)

Image = np.divide(matcontent['I32'] , highest )

highest  = np.max(Image)
lowest = np.min(Image)
print(highest, lowest)

Image_255 = Image*255
```

output:
`283.52991767049167 0.09813473030519577`
`1.0 0.000346117725817014`

```
Image.fromarray(Image_255)
```

error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-698d66d71bc6> in <module>()
----> 1 Image.fromarray(Image_255)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fromarray'
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] and the full stack trace.

Comment: add:   from PIL import Image  change your Image with something else, let us know.. can't test your code wiyhout input file , see above comment

Comment: In your code `Image` is a numpy array.  If it's meant to be a module wth a `fromarray` method, correct the variable names.

Comment: using `Image.astype(np.uint8)` solved the problem thanks

Comment: @harsha meaning Image.fromarray(np.uint8(Image_255)) ??